# Graphs from Google Forms

Tags: graph, google-sheets, auto-update

I have a form which records electricity consumption over time. This will insert values in a sheet, where the first column is called `Timestamp` and is in the form: `04/02/2016 11:03:44`.

I wanted to run some stats based on weeknumber and month from `Timestamp` and display updated graphs automatically. How would you easily achieve this?

Creating another column which references and formats the `Timestamp` column, does not work because each time a row is added by the form the references are skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using arrayformula in your other columns as these will automatically adjust to include new Form submissions.  For example, try pasting these into row 2 of your response sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),WEEKNUM(A2:A),))`

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),MONTH(A2:A),))`